# react hooks cannot read property map of undefined

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, iterable

I am working on a movie list search app and then later might try to add lazy loading. This is just for POC purpose. Might add it to my portfolio later.

So, I have first created a global `api.js` where I will put the API calls with a callback and then call an API using callbacks from the components.

```
    const PageOneApi = (callback, errorCallback) => {
      axios("https://run.mocky.io/v3/36e4f9ce-2e48-4d44-9cf8-57f6900f8e12")
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("response from page one api", response);
          callback(response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log("error from page one api", err);
          errorCallback(err);
        });
    };

export const movieListApi = {
  PageOneApi,
};
```

I have a `movieList` component:

```
function MovieList() {
  const [pageOneData, setPageOneData] = useState({});

  useEffect(async () => {
    await movieListApi.PageOneApi(
      (res) => {
        const pageOneData = res.data.page;
        setPageOneData(pageOneData);
        console.log("page one data: ", pageOneData);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }, []);

  const movieList = pageOneData.contentItems;
  console.log(movieList);

  return (
    <div>
      <h4 className="text-white p-5">{pageOneData.title}</h4>
      <div className="grid grid-flow-row grid-cols-3 grid-rows-3 gap-7 m-5">
        {movieList.map((movie) => {
          console.log("movie", movie);
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now, the problem is that I am unable to iterate through `movieList`, even though it's an array.

Comment: If you are using promises, then you don't need to pass callback functions to `PageOneApi` function; you can return the promise from the `PageOneApi` function and chain `then()` and `catch()` method calls to the function call.

Comment: [Here's a simplified version of your code](https://pastebin.com/5QYKqApa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `pageOneData` is initially an empty object, `pageOneData.contentItems` will be undefined in the first render cycle. causing movieList.map to fail as your useEffect call is made after the initial render and that fires an API which again is async and will take time to fetch the result

You can use default value for movieList to solve the error

```
const movieList = pageOneData.contentItems || [];
```

or

[Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
 <div className="grid grid-flow-row grid-cols-3 grid-rows-3 gap-7 m-5">
    {movieList?.map((movie) => {
      console.log("movie", movie);
    })}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Initially `pageOneData` is blank object so `pageOneData.contentItems` will return undefined so at first render react will throw error.

To solve this, you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) so try something like below:-

```
{movieList?.map((movie) => {
          console.log("movie", movie);
        })}
```